# Will using multiple url redirects hurt my URL?

Tags: url, seo, url-routing

Currently I'm using this link forwarding structure:

> bit.ly/{some_hash} > example.com/s/{ID} > example.com/blog/full-seo-optimized-url/

Because the id of the blog never changes but the url might change (e.g. spelling mistake), I'm forwarding my bit.ly short urls to a special subpage (/s/{UD}) that will eventually get the full url from the database and forward the visitor to the blog entry.

Pros:

- If the URL changes, the bit.ly short link will still work and forward to the updated url

(Possible) Cons:

- Might be seen as spammy method (hiding target link)?
- Might be violating any terms of service?
- ... ?

Therefore I would know, if this is a good and proper way or if I should remove the step in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those redirects will cause a slower user experience and when used will cause a loss of PageRank being sent to the destination.

I'd avoid doing it where possible.

There are URL shorteners out there that let you directly edit the destination which would avoid your need for the middle redirect.

You also want to avoid changing the destinations URL as other people will not use your fancy redirects and you will lose PageRank every time they change.

Comment: These are some points. But the redirects only add a small amount of time. Loss of Pagerank might not be very huge as Matt Cutts mentioned, Google will still follow some redirects. As I'm sharing the bit.ly Link, people will click on this link and will always get redirected to correct source. Of course I'm avoiding to change the full URL, but sometimes this happen.